# Mysql: Allow Null meaning

Tags: mysql, null

What does `"Allow Null"` mean, and what does it do?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In order to understand what "Allow Null" means, you need to understand what `NULL` is, and understand that it is different to simply a zero or blank string.

`NULL` is a special value in SQL. It indicates data that does not exist. This is different to data that is blank.

When you create a table in MySQL, it allows you to specify whether your fields are allowed to be `NULL`. If you specify "Allow Null", then it will be possible to create records with `NULL` values in those fields.

This may be useful to you in some cases. For example, a Yes/No field may be a boolean value, but if the user didn't specify their preference, you may want to set to `NULL` to indicate this rather than defaulting to yes or no.

In many cases though, allowing `NULL` can be problematic. Fields set to `NULL` can produce unexpected results in queries, because `NULL` does not follow the same rules as other values in all cases. eg: If you query the above example field `WHERE myfield != 1`, you may expect to get results for all the records which are not equal to 1. However `NULL` fields will not be returned; you need to write a special case for them.

`NULL` is also used as the default value when doing `JOIN` queries where some of the results do not have a record to join to. The unknown fields from the joined table will all be set to `NULL`.

In general, if you're not sure what to do with "Allow Null", the safest option is to set it to no allow nulls.

See the [Wikipedia entry for NULL in SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) for more info.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! Really nice explained.

Answer (score 4):

Allow Null means that when you change or insert the data you dont *need* to fill that data in. Its not compulsory.

Answer (score 4):

In essence, if you allow a null value you're saying that the field in question can contain a legitimate value (e.g.: 2011-04-02 if it was a date) as well as "NULL" (or "no value").

As such, if you imagine a situation where a field was mandatory, it should always be denoted as `NOT NULL` in the schema declaration, whereas an optional field can be left as is.

For more information, check out the [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) section of the MySQL manual, which (amongst other things) neatly summarises things thus:

> Conceptually, NULL means “a missing
>   unknown value” and it is treated
>   somewhat differently from other
>   values.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer and the link. I will definitely read it.