# Mysql not showing all 10 found rows because a value that is being selected is blank

Tags: mysql, sql

Please see the following image for context:  http://clip2net.com/s/2hHUe

I am selecting LatestMood for example from this table but as you can see the mysql is only showing 9 of the 10 found because the latest row's LatestMood is blank - how can I avoid this - or rather how can i show all of the rows regardless of if a value is blank or not.

The problem is that `mysql_num_rows` shows 10 and `mysql_fetch_array` holds 9

Comment: Please show the relevant PHP code.

Comment: it the blank value actually `NULL`. If so, be aware that null works very differently to simply a blank value. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523687/mysql-not-null-meaning/5523755#5523755 for more detail.

Comment: also - it is strongly recommended not to use the obsolete `mysql_xx()` funcs in PHP any more. Suggest switching to `mysqli_xx()` or PDO.

Comment: value is just blank, nothing in it

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Your picture has 10 rows (I counted). However, I suspect you're looking for `or latestmood is null`

Comment: Also, I'm out of close votes but this is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339201/showing-rows-0-9-10-total-query-took-0-0002-sec-latestmoodtime-blob-1

Answer (score 0):

Change your WHERE condition to:

```
LOWER(IFNULL(RealName, '')) like '%hot%'
OR LOWER(IFNULL(UserName, '')) like '%hot%'
OR LOWER(IFNULL(Location, '')) like '%hot%'
OR LOWER(IFNULL(LatestMood, '')) like '%hot%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the picture showing 10 rows :)  `0-9` is actually 10 rows because 0 is also counted as 1

```
 0 is 1st row
 1 is 2
 2 is 3
 3 is 4
 4 is 5
 5 is 6
 6 is 7
 7 is 8
 8 is 9
 9 is 10th row
```

The latest mood may be the user who didn't update his mood